# How can I change what a class inherits from at compile-time?

Tags: c++

In my quest to create a cross-platform GUI Framework, I have hit the following snag:
Suppose I have a central "Window" class, in the project's general, platform-independent include folder:

```
//include/window.hpp
class Window
{
    //Public interface
}
```

I then have several platform-dependent implementation classes, like so:

```
//src/{platform}/window.hpp
class WinWindow {...}; //Windows
class OSXWindow {...}; //OSX
class X11Window {...}; //Unix
```

Finally, there is the original Window class' .cpp file, where I want to "bind" the implementation class to the general class. Purely conceptually, this is what I want to be able to do:

```
//src/window.cpp
//Suppose we're on Windows

#include "include/window.hpp"
#include "src/win/window.hpp"
class Window : private WinWindow; //Redefine Window's inheritance
```

I know this is by no means valid C++, and that's the point. I have thought of two possible ways to solve this problem, and I have problems with both.

**pImpl-style implementation**

Make Window hold a void pointer to an implementing class, and assign that to a different window class for each platform. However, I would have to up-cast the pointer every time I want to perform a platform dependent-operation, not to mention include the platform dependent file everywhere.

**Preprocessor directives**

```
class Window :
#ifdef WIN32
private WinWindow
#else ifdef X11
private X11Window //etc.
```

This, however, sounds more like a hack than an actual solution to the problem.

What to do? Should I change my design completely? Do any of my possible solutions hold a little bit of water?

Comment: @VincentSavard OP explains clearly what he needs and the question is asked in the right way, according to SO rules.

Comment: @ΔλЛ I'm not sure what this has to do with anything. Either the OP is confident he explained himself clearly enough and doesn't feel the need to add such a comment, or he isn't and he should take the time necessary for him to be confident about his own question.

Comment: It seems sort of like you have two conceptually different roles for the `Window` class--one where it defines the interface the platforms should implement, and one where it's implemented in terms of a platform-specific class, and isn't an interface so much as a concrete object to manipulate. Separating them should resolve things--have the interface part *be* an abstract interface implemented by different platforms. Have the concrete part hold some reference to the interface so you can act on a defined set of operations universal to all windows.

Comment: I added that final statement in case I made some formatting mistakes or something

Comment: @CRefice You don't need to include that statement. Your question's format was nice. If someone has concerns over formatting mistakes or what you meant, they will comment.

Comment: I'm not sure but what about using 'multiple inheritance' technique?

Comment: @GeorgeGaál What does multiple inheritance have to do with this? There is no clear reason why you'd need to have multiple inheritance here, and in general, multiple inheritance should be avoided.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Using typedef to hide the preprocessor

You could simply typedef the appropriate window type instead:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
    typedef WinWindow WindowType;
#elif defined // etc
```

Then your window class could be:

```
class Window : private WindowType {
};
```

This isn't a very robust solution, though. It is better to think in a more Object Oriented way, but OO programming in C++ comes at a runtime cost, unless you use the

### Curiously repeating template pattern

You could use the [curiously repeating template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
template<class WindowType>
class WindowBase {
public:
    void doSomething() {
        static_cast<WindowType *>(this)->doSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

Then you could do

```
class WinWindow : public WindowBase<WinWindow> {
public:
    void doSomethingElse() {
        // code
    }
};
```

And to use it (assuming C++ 14 support):

```
auto createWindow() {
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return WinWindow{};
#elif UNIX
    return X11Window{};
#endif
}
```

With C++ 11 only:

```
auto createWindow()
    ->
#ifdef WINDOWS
    WinWindow
#elif defined UNIX
    X11Window
#endif
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return WinWindow{};
#elif defined UNIX
    return X11Window{};
#endif
}
```

I recommend using `auto` when you use it, or using it in combination with a typedef:

```
auto window = createWindow();
window.doSomething();
```

### Object Oriented Style

You could make your `Window` class be an abstract class:

```
class Window {
protected:
    void doSomething();
public:
    virtual void doSomethingElse() = 0;
};
```

Then define your platform-dependent classes as subclasses of `Window`. Then all you'd have to do is have the preprocessor directives in one place:

```
std::unique_ptr<Window> createWindow() {
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return new WinWindow;
#elif defined OSX
    return new OSXWindow;
// etc
}
```

Unfortunately, this incurs a runtime cost through calls to the virtual function. The CRTP version resolves calls to the "virtual function" at compile time instead of at runtime.

Additionally, this requires the `Window` to be declared on the heap whereas CRTP doesn't; this might be a problem depending on the use case, but in general, it doesn't matter that much.

---

Ultimately, you do have to use the `#ifdef` somewhere, so you can determine the platform (or you could use a library that determines the platform, but it probably uses `#ifdef` too), the question is just where to hide it.

Comment: In the "object oriented style" the runtime cost doesn't come from a "requirement of pointers" - the implementation of `baseClassFunction()` inthe CRTP also requires use of a pointer.   The runtime cost comes due to requirement for virtual function dispatch - which happens at run time - whereas CRTP resolves that at compile time.

Comment: @Peter That's true. I guess I was also trying to say that it had to be declared on the heap with the "object oriented style", unless I understand C++ less than I think I do.

Comment: It is necessary to create the objects, regardless, but calling a non-static member function implicitly dereferences the `this` pointer, regardless of how the object is created.   And objects don't get "declared on the heap".

Comment: @Peter Yes my language wasn't the best. I meant that the only way I know how to do it in this "object oriented" way is to use `new`, which places the objects in the heap and returns a pointer. It's useful to be able to place the objects on the stack

Comment: Yeah, but needing to "use `new`" (i.e. to dynamically allocate the object) happens exactly once for each object.   That incurs runtime cost if objects are repeatedly being created and destroyed - whether or not that involves dynamic allocation or not.

Comment: @Peter The way I understand it, one should avoid using the heap if at all possible. That's why I state that as a problem.

Comment: That's ancient guidance.   Became obsolete not long after the arc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120173/discussion-between-justin-and-peter).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern to implement *static polymorphism*:

```
class WindowBase {
     virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

template<class WindowType>
class Window : public WindowBase {

    // Static cast when accessing the actual implementation:
    void doSomething() {
         static_cast<WindowType*>(this)->doSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

---

```
class X11WindowImpl : public Window<X11WindowImpl> {
    void doSomethingElse() {
       // blah ...
    }
};
```

---

```
class Win32WindowImpl : public Window<Win32WindowImpl> {
    void doSomethingElse() {
       // blah ...
    }
};
```

Since your code will be compiled to satisfy a particular target, this should be the leanest option.

Answer (score -1):

It's okey. You could also write one class and define it's content using #ifdef etc., but your solution isn't a hack. Just a proper way to write multiplatform code if you have no other choice.

Comment: Preprocessor options is one of the worse choices to go.